# c++ string, build function that removes character 'b' and replaces character 'a' by two 'd'

Tags: c++, string, function

In a test conducted on Hackerrank platform, I was asked to **build a function that returns a string after removing all the 'b' and replacing all the 'a' by two 'd'**. E.g: i/p: ***abacdb***  o/p ***ddddcd*** After searching through various literature I was able to come up with this program:(**Please note I wasnt allowed to change the function type**)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char* ReplaceandRemove(char* s){
    int write_idx=0;
    int a_count=0;
    for(const char &C : s){
        if(C!='b'){
            s[write_idx++]=C;
        }
        if(C=='a'){
            ++a_count;
        }
    }

    s.resize(write_idx+a_count);
    int curr_idx=write_idx - 1;
    write_idx = s.size()-1;
    while(curr_idx>=0){
        if(curr_idx=='a'){
            s[write_idx--]='d';
            s[write_idx--]='d';
        }
        else{
            s[write_idx--]=s[curr_idx];
        }
        --curr_idx;
    }
    return s;

}

int main() {
    char s[6]={'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b'};
    ReplaceandRemove(s);
    cout<<s;

    return 0;
}
```

The program is giving a lot of errors that are beyond my understanding:

```
In function 'char* ReplaceandRemove(char*)':
6:25: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(char*&)'
s){

6:25: note: candidates are:
42:0,
52,
40,
41,
42,
38,
39,
1:
89:5: note: template constexpr const _Tp* std::begin(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)


89:5: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
6:25: note: mismatched types 'std::initializer_list<_Tp>' and 'char*'
s){

51:0,
40,
41,
42,
38,
39,
1:
87:5: note: template _Tp* std::begin(_Tp (&)[_Nm])


87:5: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
6:25: note: mismatched types '_Tp [_Nm]' and 'char*'
s){

51:0,
40,
41,
42,
38,
39,
1:
58:5: note: template decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&)


58:5: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In substitution of 'template decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&) [with _Container = char*]':
6:25: required from here
58:5: error: request for member 'begin' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'char* const'
48:5: note: template decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&)


48:5: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In substitution of 'template decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&) [with _Container = char*]':
6:25: required from here
48:5: error: request for member 'begin' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'char*'
6:25: error: no matching function for call to 'end(char*&)'
s){

6:25: note: candidates are:
42:0,
52,
40,
41,
42,
38,
39,
1:
99:5: note: template constexpr const _Tp* std::end(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)


99:5: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
6:25: note: mismatched types 'std::initializer_list<_Tp>' and 'char*'
s){

51:0,
40,
41,
42,
38,
39,
1:
97:5: note: template _Tp* std::end(_Tp (&)[_Nm])


97:5: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
6:25: note: mismatched types '_Tp [_Nm]' and 'char*'
s){

51:0,
40,
41,
42,
38,
39,
1:
78:5: note: template decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&)


78:5: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In substitution of 'template decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&) [with _Container = char*]':
6:25: required from here
78:5: error: request for member 'end' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'char* const'
68:5: note: template decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&)


68:5: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In substitution of 'template decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&) [with _Container = char*]':
6:25: required from here
68:5: error: request for member 'end' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'char*'
15:7: error: request for member 'resize' in 's', which is of non-class type 'char*'


17:19: error: request for member 'size' in 's', which is of non-class type 'char*'
```

**Please help me to find out what mistake I am doing**

Answer (score 1):

```
for(const char &C : s){
```

`s` is a `char *`, a plain char pointer. Range iteration works only over those types which are supported by `std::begin()` and `std::end()`. A plain pointer isn't one of them.

```
s.resize(write_idx+a_count);
```

`s` is a `char *`, a plain char pointer. It is not a class that implements a method called `resize()`.

```
write_idx = s.size()-1;
```

`s` is a `char *`, a plain char pointer. It is not a class that implements a method called `size()`.

The overall problem with the shown code is that it assumes that `s` is some kind of a class, like a `std::string`, that implements various methods. It is not, it is a plain `char *`.

And that's the reason for your compilation errors.